How to extract audio from a video in Flutter?
I have an image picker in Flutter to get the video from the device, and then I created a function to extract the audio using ffmpeg_kit_flutter package.
 Future<void> _convertVideoToAudio() async {
    if (_pickedVideo != null) {
      bool? permissionGranted = await _requestStoragePermission();
      if (permissionGranted != true) {
        print("Storage permission denied.");
        return;
      }

      String videoPath = _pickedVideo!.path;
      _outputPath = await getOutputFilePath(); // Get platform-specific path

      try {
        // Ensure the output directory exists
        await Directory(path.dirname(_outputPath)).create(recursive: true);

        await FFmpegKit.execute(
            "-i $videoPath -vn -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 $_outputPath"); // FFmpeg command
        print("Video converted to audio successfully!");
        _showSuccessDialog(); // Display success dialog

        try {
          final String fileName = path.basename(_outputPath);
          final transcription =
              await _sendAudioForTranscription(_outputPath, fileName);

          if (transcription != null) {
            setState(() {
              _transcription = transcription;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _transcription = "Transcription failed";
            });
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error in transcription request: $e');
          setState(() {
            _transcription = "Network request failed";
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error converting video: $e");
        _showErrorDialog(); // Display error dialog
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          _pickedVideo = null; // Clear selected video
        });
      }
    } else {
      print("Please pick a video first.");
    }
  }

and for getting the path I have this function
 Future<String> getOutputFilePath() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final downloadsDirectory = Directory('${directory.path}/downloads');
    if (!(await downloadsDirectory.exists())) {
      await downloadsDirectory.create(recursive: true);
    }
    final String fileName = path
        .basename(_pickedVideo!.path)
        .replaceAll('.mp4', '.mp3'); // Replace extension
    final filePath = '${downloadsDirectory.path}/$fileName';
    return filePath;
  }

but this is not working somehow. Because after I get the audio I'm uploading it to a server with http, then it displays that there is no path where the audio supposed to be.

This seems to be a duplicate of your question yesterday.

@RichardHeap it's related question.

Creating mp3 files requires an available encoder.
From the documentation for ffmpeg_kit_flutter:

FFmpeg includes built-in encoders for some popular formats. However,
there are certain external libraries that needs to be enabled in order
to encode specific formats/codecs. For example, to encode an mp3 file
you need lame or shine library enabled.
ffmpeg-kit provides eight packages that include different sets of
external libraries. These packages are named according to the external
libraries included. Refer to the Packages wiki page to see the names
of those packages and external libraries included in each one of them.

Run pub add ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio to enable the audio package.

How do i use it then? like i have an XFile type to pick video. how do i extract the audio from it using this?
